# Can't resolve syntax error in Conversation flow : Watson Co

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

The question is : why does the conversation print the JSON output instead of plain text , as it should. Next, why is the context variable, size, not getting set?

The Watson response being thrown as JSON is, also the context variable, size as specified below, is not getting set :   {
  "output": {
    "text": "Great, a @size pizza, what toppings would you like"
  },
  "context": {
    "size": "@size"
  }
}

[image]

I can't find any error, in the Advanced Watson output for the dialog nodes, where the user first specifies the size of the pizza followed by the toppings. The output from the first node, and shown in the above picture.

Thank you !

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What are you trying to achieve and what isn't currently working as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why Conversation responds with JSON is because you have a JSON in the response part of the dialog nodes there. If you cut and paste it in the "Advanced Editor" I think you'll get what you're looking for. Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: I have an entity called toppings, and would like to display the context value using entities['toppings'].toString() Is this the correct way to get the value